# VGA display is blank after disconnect/reconnect

Tags: usb, vga, lcd, xubuntu

At home I sometimes disconnect a large LCD VGA display (and USB mouse/keyboard) from my XUbuntu/xfce server to use it with my laptop (mostly to play games).

As long as the LCD is not disconnected I can turn the display OFF, and when a couple days later I turn the LCD back ON it shows xcfe just the way I left it without any delay, both the mouse and the keyboard work as expected.

Yet when I disconnect the VGA and the mouse/keyboard for a couple of days - once I reconnect the LCD screen stays blank, nothing seems to make a difference but a hard reboot of the server.

A KVM switch is on my list to buy next but I would like to know the reason why this might be happening?

Also come to think of it I do not just disconnect the VGA alone, I also disconnect/reconnect the USB keyboard/mouse too.

I am clueless: BIOS wake-up config, headless config, it is not VGA but USB issue (keyboard/mouse disconnected)? Is it the LCD?

Thanks for reading!

CLOSED on 01-16-2015

I never got to the end of this, but I bought a KVM and now there is immediate response from all PCs connected to it.

Comment: Hi, Suspect this might helps. Disconnect the RAM once from your machine and clean the RAM at its golden colored edge, once after done this now insert in the RAM slot and turn it ON, now check whether the reported problem goes off not. Also please make ensure that whether VGA cable between CPU and Monitor are properly fixed or not.

Comment: I am not sure about messing again with the RAM sticks. The server stays on and on unless I disconnect VGA, and USB mouse and keyboard. I did place the RAM sticks inside myself, but again - the server stays on and on and on... until I disconnect the VGA and the USB keyboard/mouse. I am not sure if you roger that.